# Htaccess and rewrite/deny

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to deny access to a file using one URL, but allow access using another?

Example:

The actual URL is www.domain.com/index.php but I want to refuse access using that URL, but I still want to be able to display the file using www.domain.com/index.php/somestring

Is this possble?

Comment: Is the "somestring" part supposed to be a GET variable?  Can you give a little context?  Why do you want to block people from using just index.php?

Comment: No, it's just a alphanumerical string that will be known. The index.php will have a different name and be a login file that I want to hide.

Comment: Is a specific one or are there multiple strings that will take the place of "somestring"?  If there are multiple, is there a specific pattern to the string?

Comment: I hoped it would be possible for the user to define the alphanumerical "somestring", and then store it in the DB, and generate the .htacces based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of *generating* the `.htaccess` with the strings stored in the DB, you would be better off writing the `.htaccess` file so that it treats "somestring" as a GET variable.  You would then check if "somestring" is in your DB and if it is, you show the page.  Otherwise, you do a php header redirect.

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

In your `index.php` first, grab the GET variable, check for it's presence in the DB, and if it is present, then show the page.  Otherwise, you can use a header redirect to send the user to a different page.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];  // You will probably want to escape this
```

Then, wrap the entire page in an if statement and only display the page if the id exists in the database.